# Basic encrypt and decrypt method not working C++ 11

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, encryption

I am making two basic encrypt and decrypt functions just to encrypt strings, But it seems to not work when certain characters are entered...

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char characters[27][2] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," "};
char encrypted[27][2] = {"!","@","#","$","\%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=","~","`","{","}","[","]","|","\\",":",";","'","."};

bool replace(std::string& str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    size_t start_pos = str.find(from);
    if(start_pos == std::string::npos)
    return false;
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    return true;
}

string encrypt(string str) {
    int i = -1;
    for(string c : characters) {
        i += 1;
        replace(str,c,encrypted[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

string decrypt(string str) {
    int i = -1;
    for(string e : encrypted) {
        i += 1;
        replace(str,e,characters[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    string str = "testing-foo!";
    str = encrypt(str);
    cout << str;
    str = decrypt(str);
    cout << str;
}
```

I am using std c++ 11 when compiling so I can initialize the arrays.
The output encrypted version of variable **str** is ]%[t(=&-^~o! and the output decrypted version of **]%[t(=&-^~o!** is **testinglfooa**. It seems to replace - with l and ! with a.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why `characters` and `encrypted` are static 2D arrays?

Comment: @Bentoy13 what do you mean?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: @JesperJuhl While that is a very valid point, I very much doubt OP wants this for actual security purposes. It looks more like an exercise to learn with than a real application.

Comment: What happens if i goes beyond the size of arrays?

Comment: @ZDF it does the same thing.

Comment: Your string  should contain ONLY characters from `characters` array, but `!` and `-` 
 are not.

Comment: @JoshuaBenfield Yes, sorry. I didn't notice what you're iterating over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you do not have the mapping for every character that you have in your encryption.

You only provide alphabet and space character, whereas in your string `testing-foo!`, you have character `-` and `!`. These characters are not encrypted during your call to `encrypt` function. But, when decrypting, these characters where decrypted as `l` and `a` respectively.

Solution: try adding your list to cater character `-` and `!` too .

Comment: Another option would be to map any source symbols that are in  `encrypted` but not in `characters` to an escape sequence preceding the character. Remember to also escape the escape character. The downside is that your output string will be longer than your starting string.

Answer (score 0):

When you encrypt one character at a time, the set of the possible encrypted characters must be the same as the set of the possible original characters, or you must be sure that any message will never contain a character from the encrypted set not belonging to the original one. If you do not respect that rule, the encrypt/decrypt operation cannot be guaranteed to be the identity.

Here your message contains characters from the encrypted set, so the crypt/encrypt is not the identity.

---

Unrelated, but your storage and processing of `characters` and `encrypted` is *weird*. If you manage to get your code to work without errors, you really should submit it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to improve it.